# Need to remove _DEV string from directory names using ant

Tags: ant

All our directory names in development contains names like demo_DEV,sample_DEV.
Now our requirement is to remove those _DEV from the directory names & put names like demo,sample.

I am trying this using ant.

Requesting your help.

Regards,
Kunal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ant to achieve this, you could do something like:

```
<move todir="${basedir}">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="**/*_DEV"/>
    </fileset>
    <filtermapper>
        <replacestring from="_DEV" to=""/>
    </filtermapper>
</move>
```

where `${basedir}` should point to the root directory containing all subdirectories you want to rename and assuming that the suffix `_DEV` is only used for resource you want to rename.